# Error with "Unsigned Char * " in DLL imported on C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have been trying to use a VB DLL supplied with a Contactless mifare Card reader, in C#, however there's a problem passing a variable type. The original code is:

```
READER_API int __stdcall  RDR_LoginToSector(UCHAR Sector, UCHAR KeyType, unsigned char * KEY);
```

The UCHAR can be used as "uint" or "byte" without problems, however the "unsigned char *" is not working

I have tried calling it as various types:

```
[DllImport("SmartReader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] public static extern int RDR_LoginToSector(byte Sector, byte KeyType, IntPtr KEY);
byte[] D = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
IntPtr F = new IntPtr();
F = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(D));
Logged = RDR_LoginToSector((byte) 0x01, (byte)0x60, F);

[DllImport("SmartReader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl] public static extern int RDR_LoginToSector(byte Sector, byte KeyType, StringBuilder KEY);
StringBuilder E = new StringBuilder(6);
E.Append((byte)0xff);
E.Append((byte)0xff);
E.Append((byte)0xff);
E.Append((byte)0xff);
E.Append((byte)0xff);
E.Append((byte)0xff);
Logged = RDR_LoginToSector((byte) 0x01, (byte)0x60, E);

[DllImport("SmartReader.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern int RDR_LoginToSector(byte Sector, byte KeyType, byte[] KEY); 
byte[] D = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
Logged = RDR_LoginToSector((byte) 0x01, (byte)0x60, D);

[DllImport("SmartReader.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern int RDR_LoginToSector(byte Sector, byte KeyType, char[] KEY); 
char[] C = { (char)0xff, (char)0xff, (char)0xff, (char)0xff, (char)0xff, (char)0xff };
Logged = RDR_LoginToSector((byte) 0x01, (byte)0x60, C);
```

I also tried with the "ref" statement without success.

In all of the methods the return is 3 which means Login Failure. I double checked the Key using an Android app I was working and could log correctly, also the compiled source that comes with it also works with this key.

All methods that does not require "unsigned char * " work properly, like those to verify the type of the card, opening the COM port and such.

Any ideas?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: 1) Strings are null terminated (include +1 char for that). 2) Strings are Unicode! E.Append((byte)0xff); will not do what you expect (same is true for all your examples. use System.Byte like your first example (but add a null terminator "0" at the end).

Comment: @Adriano mabye some code will help

Comment: @MauricioGracia I'm little bit busy, that's why I posted just a comment!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to declare this is:

```
[DllImport("SmartReader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
public static extern int RDR_LoginToSector(
    byte Sector, 
    byte KeyType, 
    [In] byte[] Key
);
```

This declaration matches the native declaration that you provided. Your attempts used the wrong calling convention, and the final parameter should be `byte[]`. In fact, you could even omit the `CallingConvention` because `Stdcall` is the default. However, it does not hurt to be explicit. Likewise, the `[In]` could be omitted but again being explicit is wise.

The error indicated by the return value therefore means that you are passing incorrect parameters. It's hard for us to debug the parameters that you pass since we do not know the specifics of this function.

So, what I am trying to say is that if you use the p/invoke above, you can remove interop from the list of possible failure modes. In fact, to be completely sure of that you should write a test program in C++ that calls the function successfully. That way you can debug the parameters you use without having the worry at the back of your mind that it is the interop that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, parameters should be a range of 0x00 to 0x0f to Sector, on KeyType 0x60 for KeyA and 0x61 for KeyB, the Key itself is comprised of 6 bytes. Thanks, I will test this as soon as I can and return.

Comment: I have tried without success, maybe buggy DLL, however in C++ it worked.
I contacted the supplier and they said will send the Serial commands to access the Reader, so I will make my own library.

Comment: If you showed the C++ calling code that works it's likely we could spot the mismatch

Answer (score 0):

As your C function is declared `__stdcall`, you should use the matching calling convention: `CallingConvention.StdCall`.

The Unicode Charset isn't helping you any. I think you want to use the byte array for the last parameter (aka, Key) and bytes for the first two parameters. (Your third example in looks right other than the calling convention and the unnecessary Charset.)

You might also verify the byte order of your data in the byte array. I'm not sure how it is used in other areas.